# enums with multiple values to have description

Tags: java, enums

```
public enum MyType {
  Type1("A","B"),
  Type2("C","D" );


  private List<String> value;

  MyType(String... value) {
    this.value = Arrays.asList(value);
  }

  public static Optional<MyType> fromString(String type) {
    return Arrays.stream(MyType.values())
        .filter(typ -> MyType.getValue().contains(typ)).findFirst();
  }

  private List<String> getValue() {
    return value;
  }

}
```

I want the enum Type1 , and Type 2 to have a description as well

MyType1.fromString("A") will return Optional .I want a method to return value "Type1"

Comment: Do you mean you want another field for the description?

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on what you mean description is in this case

Answer (score 0):

If you want a "description" you can add one, but since you have a vararg it must be the first argument. Also, your `fromString` method ignores the `type` argument (so you should fix that too). Something like,

```
public enum MyType {
    Type1("Type1 Description", "A", "B"), Type2("Type2 Description", "C", "D");

    private String description;
    private List<String> value;

    MyType(String description, String... value) {
        this.description = description;
        this.value = Arrays.asList(value);
    }

    public static Optional<MyType> fromString(String type) {
        return Arrays.stream(MyType.values())
                .filter(typ -> typ.getValue().contains(type)).findFirst();
    }

    private List<String> getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
}
```

Comment: can we use .name property if I want the value of decription to be Type1

Comment: That is the name indeed

Comment: You should prefer using MyType.valueOf instead of fromString